# Best way to create tab application

Tags: android

I want to develop app where there will be three activities :- friends,  main activity and another one

So I was initially thinking of making it like whatsapp layout having three tabs with swipe change

But when I made viewpage fragment tabs then issue was that when shipping from tab1 to tab2 tab 3 gets initialized,  and on swipe each fragment go oncreate,  onstop lifestyle

So how do I make my app
Friends java includes getting phone contacts
And main activity is also such that I don't want onrestart to occour

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) method to set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page. The default value is 1. In your case you should set it to 2 so none of your fragments will be recreated.